# Selenium DOM searcher returning the page body rather than a WebElement

Tags: python, selenium, dom, web-scraping, multiprocessing

I'm working on a crawler for news websites like Techcrunch, Bloomberg, etc., all of which share a similar pattern of lazy-loading article cards with the click of a "Load More"-type button.

I've designed it to run a load procedure and digest procedure in parallel using `multiprocessing`. For context, the `run` method below is in a `Crawler` class used to abstract different site elements so that a scraper need not be written for each site. Here's the entry method:

```
def run(self):
    """ Runs a crawler. """
    binary: FirefoxBinary = FirefoxBinary(firefox_path="/usr/bin/firefox")
    self.driver: Firefox = Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
    self.driver.get(self.url)

    self.load_pipe, self.digest_pipe = Pipe()

    load_proc: Process = Process(target=self._load_content)
    load_proc.start()

    digest_proc: Process = Process(target=self._digest_content)
    digest_proc.start()
```

The issue arises in the load procedure, implemented in the `_load_content` method. Specifically in the first line, with the call of `find_element_by_class_name`.

```
def _load_content(self):
    """ Loads more content. """
    loader: WebElement = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name(self.loader_name)
    ...
```

When testing it synchronously in non-parallel, the function returned a `WebElement` representing the target button. But, when ran in parallel, it returned a `str` representing the entire page body, which then threw `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'click'`.

I made sure that the driver is still intact when in `_load_content`, which it is, but the method still returns a `str` rather than a `WebElement`. What's odd is that, if no element with the given class identifier is found, it raises `NoSuchElementException`. So why is it returning the HTML body as a `str`? What am I missing? Does `multiprocessing` mess with the driver API somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The `WebDriver` API is **not thread-safe**, due to restrictions on the browser itself. The browser expects one command at a time, so the processes have to run synchronously in non-parallel. Even if you the resources were available to do so, running multiple browser instances would not solve the problem as state would not be shared.

A potential solution to this is the implementation of a callback structure between the load and digest procedures. Like this (pseudo-code):

```
while article cards are available
    digest article cards

if no article cards are available
    load more article cards
    start digesting article cards again
```

Chances are the malfunction in `find_element_by_class_name` is caused by the state of the driver instance being corrupted or the browser bindings fail to operate how the API expects them to.